# Gatsby + Netlify add push notification

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps, gatsby, netlify, netlify-function

(have seen a few similar questions, but they do not solve my problem and none of them have a full example.)

I am trying to add push notification to my Gatsby + Netlify CMS website.

What I have:

1. I have a website created by Gatsbyjs + Netlify CMS and hosted on Netlify. I also turned this website into a PWA.
2. I found that there is a lambda function in this website under folder lambda brought by Netlify CMS.
3. I have a Windows Service which runs at the background of my PC and will call the lambda function to create push notification.

Here is the architecture of my project:
[image]

What I want to do is :
the Windows Service(WS) will trigger push notification once events on my PC happened, it(WS) calls the Lambda in the Netlify, the lambda then sends out Push Notification to the PWA.

I saw some posts saying the push notification needs some backend running to send out notifications, so they use something like Subscriber, Firebase messaging or Pusher etc. And I have been searching for a day, tried a few code with no luck.

I found that Gatsby has offline and service worker plugins, but even the latest version of them seem not capable of doing push notification.
I also found some pieces and bits here and there, but not a complete example. After searching a day long, my brain stops working.

Could someone point me to the right direction and show me a full example for Gatsby + Netlify CMS receiving triggering messages from a Windows service to bring push notification on the PWA?